# How edit configuration files with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, edit

I have some configuration files(and scripts) which I want to edit with a bash script:

```
.
.
.
# ... foo ...
foo
.
.
.
```

I used this:

```
sed -i 's/foo/bar/'
```

but as expected it will edit foo in comment line too, how can I prevent that?

Comment: `sed -i '/^ *#/! s/foo/bar/'` ? It there it is guaranteed that the comment line always starts with `#`, with no leading spaces, you can drop ` *` before `#`

Comment: @anishsane why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
sed -i '/^ *#/! s/foo/bar/' filename
```

explanation (in addition to your original `sed` command):

1. `s` command can take [addresses](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses).
2. `/^ *#/` Implies any line starting with `*#`
3. `!` after the address negates its effect.

So all lines NOT starting with `*#` are affected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this also

```
 sed '/^[^#]/s/foo/bar/g' file_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
sed -i 's/\[^#\]foo/bar/g' filename
```